# QStyle ownership

Tags: c++, qt

When using styles in Qt applications, I ran across an interesting problem of `QStyle` ownership. `QStyle` inherits from `QObject`, which typically accepts `QObject* parent` as a constructor parameter to manage the lifetime of its child. But `QStyle`'s constructor does not have this constructor parameter. First question - why is that?

Moreover when setting style to the whole application with `QApplication::setStyle(QStyle * style)`, the documentation says that the application object takes the ownership of the style. So writing (as in docs) `app->setStyle(new MyWonderStyle());` should be safe and the application should delete the style when not used any more. I hope it does that.

But for `QWidget::setStyle(QStyle* style)` the documentation says that the ownership is not transferred. So in my view writing `widget->setStyle(new MyWonderStyle());` results in memory leak if the style of the widget is set more than once or when the widget is deleted.

So my question - what is the best practice for managing custom styles especially the ownership in Qt? Is there some standard way or is it completely up to the developer to handle it?

Comment: The documentation also says that it is best practice to use `QApplication::setStyle`. Why do you want to set your style specifically for a single `QWidget` and change it multiple times?

Comment: @ Jeffrey: I came to a very large legacy code and saw memory leaks like `widget->setStyle(new MyStyle());` the application probably does not set the style for a widget multiple times (but generally it could) but the widgets definitely get destroyed before the end of the program, leaving the created styles as orphans. So I was curious how to fix this without completely redesigning the code.

Comment: If that is the case, I would just change `MyStyle()` to `MyStyle(widget)` and be done with it. It is not the cleanest solution, but it solves your memory leaks.

Comment: But my styles inherit from `QStyle` via `QProxyStyle` and these classes do not have constructor which would take `parent` as a parameter, as I wrote above. I believe I can create such a constructor in my class and then I could call `setParent(widget)` in the constructor body but... I guess there is a reason why `QStyle` does not take `parent` in the constructor, which I do not understand.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Excuse my lack of research. A look in the `QStyle` source code didn't give me much of an answer either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that `QApplication::setStyle(QStyle*)` takes ownership of `QStyle` because there is an overloaded function `QApplication::setStyle(QString)`. This function creates a `QStyle` object internally and takes ownership of it because there is no other option in that case. Taking ownership in one function and not taking it in another one could result in confusion.

On the other hand, `QWidget` does not take ownership of `QStyle` because you may want to assign the same style to multiple `QWidget`s.

Lack of `QStyle(QObject*)` constructor is probably just an oversight. You can safely use `setParent(QObject*)` instead. In fact, `QApplication::setStyle(QStyle*)` uses `setParent` to take ownership of `QStyle`.

Comment: I agree. The legacy application should be setting ownership of styles, and the derived style constructors should be taking a `QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR` even if the `QStyle` constructor doesn't!